# Simple framework for looped applications

Tags: java, framework

I wrote up a quick API to help me save time while writing applications that require either a delay or frame rate. It should require me to implement a `void run()` method, which may or may not be annotated with the `@Loop` I created. If it doesn't contain the annotation, it will simply call the `run()` method once. If it is annotated, the client can specify either an `fps` (frames per second) or a `delay` (`fps` has priority over `delay`; if both are specified, `fps` will be used).

```
import vapp.App;
import vapp.Loop;

public class TestApp extends App {

    @Loop(fps=60)
    protected void run() {
        //my code
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

This is pretty straightforward for the client. I'll accept any suggestions on this part, but what I really want to get checked out is the framework itself.

- I'm not sure if my `launch()` method is breakable. I've tried breaking it, but couldn't find a way to. I haven't gotten any opinions on this yet, and I've been using it for a few months, so I would love to get some suggestions.
- I have `AppEngine` to encapsulate the `Thread` for the app, as well was the `boolean` that manages it. I then pass in my `appLogic`, which the logic handles:

  - Checking if the `run()` method is annotated with `@Loop` (if not, just call `run()`).
  - Check if a frame rate is specified. If so, *start a loop that manages frame rate*. If not, check if delay is specified; *start a loop that simply sleeps for the delay*. If a delay or fps isn't specified, *start a loop with no limitations*.
- Non-abstract method with no implementation. Is this the only way to ensure the subclass isn't forced to declare this method, but can if they want to?

I don't like how I create different conditional statements, each containing their own loop. I know something like this is logically needed, but it doesn't look elegant. I would love to clean it up.

Feel free to use these files for yourself if you find it functional.

**Loop.java**

```
package vapp;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Loop {
    public int delay() default 0;
    public int fps() default 0;
}
```

**App.java**

```
package vapp;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public abstract class App {
    private AppEngine engine;

    public App() {
        engine = new AppEngine(appLogic);
    }

    protected static final void launch() {
        StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
        for(int i = 0; i < stackTrace.length; i++) {
            if(stackTrace[i].getClassName().equals(App.class.getName())) {
                try {
                    App app = (App) Class.forName(stackTrace[i+1].getClassName()).newInstance();
                    app.start();
                    return;
                } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void start() {
        if (engine.isRunning())
            throw new IllegalStateException();

        init();
        engine.start();
    }

    private Runnable appLogic = () -> {
        try {
            Method runMethod = getClass().getDeclaredMethod("run");
            Class<Loop> loopClass = Loop.class;

            if(runMethod.isAnnotationPresent(loopClass)) {
                Loop loop = runMethod.getAnnotation(loopClass);
                int fps = loop.fps();
                int delay = loop.delay();

                try {
                    if(fps > 0) {
                        int timePerFrame = 1000/fps;
                        while(engine.isRunning()) {
                            long start = System.nanoTime();
                            run();
                            long sleepTime = (System.nanoTime() - start)/10000000 + timePerFrame;

                            if(sleepTime > 0) {
                                Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
                            } else {
                                Thread.yield();
                            }
                        }
                    } else if(delay > 0) {
                        while(engine.isRunning()) {
                            run();
                            Thread.sleep(delay);
                        }
                    } else {
                        while(engine.isRunning()) {
                            run();
                        }
                    }
                }catch(InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                run();
            }
        }catch(NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    };

    protected void init() { };
    protected abstract void run();
}
```

**AppEngine.java**

```
package vapp;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

public class AppEngine {
    private AtomicBoolean running;
    private Runnable appLogic;

    public AppEngine(Runnable appLogic) {
        this.appLogic = appLogic;

        running = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    }

    public final void start() {
        running.getAndSet(true);
        new Thread(appLogic).start();
    }

    public final void stop() {
        running.getAndSet(false);
    }

    public final boolean isRunning() {
        return running.get();
    }
}
```

I use an `AtomicBoolean` in case another thread attempts to stop the application at the same time the application attempts to stop itself. Is it overkill to use `AtomicBoolean` in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This idea is cool, I have some suggestions, though.

First off, you definitely should add JavaDoc to your annotation.

I wouldn't know that fps is preferred over delay, if you hadn't written it in your question (well I could find out, but it'd be a hassle). This should be done by documentation.
You can also document default values and usage constraints there, which brings me to the next point:

Your annotation only works if you annotate the run method. You might want to consider changing that a little and grab the method depending on the annotation you have (and not check for the annotation on your run method).
But that's mostly up to you ;)

Next thing I want to talk about is the units you're using.

Your delay is an `int`. I *strongly* assume the delay is given in milliseconds. If you'd want to reuse this it might be interesting to allow specifying the delay with an arbitrary `TimeUnit`, but that's future talk.

What's more interesting is things like this code:

> ```
> int timePerFrame = 1000 / fps;
> ```

time as what? be explicit and tell the reader exactly what you mean and say: `msPerFrame`

It's somewhat similar when you grab the sleepTime. When first reading this I was somewhat.. confused. Tell the reader you need to divide by 1 mil. because you need to get from nanoseconds to milliseconds.

### BUG ALERT

Btw, that's a bug right there. Counting the zeroes I'm getting to 10 mil. instead of 1. To prevent this you can write numeric literals with underscores in between them for easier overview:

```
long sleepTime = (System.nanoTime() - start) / 1_000_000 + msPerFrame;
```

**BUG EXTERMINATION COMPLETE**

Moving swiftly on to how you handle delay. It's very interesting to see the difference in how you solved the runtime of run problem from fps to delay.

I'd have expected you to do the same thing as with the fps. Instead you wait for run to complete before counting down the delay. If you want to have the same handling so fps and delay are usable interchangeably, you should do the following:

```
while (engine.isRunning()) {
     long start = System.nanoTime();
     run();
     long remainingDelay = delay - ((System.nanoTime() - start) / 1_000_000);
     
     if (remainingDelay > 0) {
        Thread.sleep(remainingDelay);
     } else {
        Thread.yield();
     }
}
```

which actually was another (rather minor) bug.

Movig swiftly on to your AppEngine, where I see you do the following twice:

> ```
> running.getAndSet(...);
> ```

Which makes me ask myself: Why not just use `set()` or `lazySet()`? It seems you used to return booleans, eh? Oh and another thing:

If you already make all the methods you have `final`, why not also make the class `final`? Then you can even remove the final from all the methods you have ;)

Comment: `AppEngine` was meant to be subclassed, although I removed that; forgot to polish it up. `set` is documented as `unconditionally sets the boolean`, while `getAndSet` states that it atomically sets it. As for `lazySet`, it was questionable when I first read the documentation;; *eventually* sets the boolean doesn't sound like what I need. Nice catch on the 1m bug, and `msPerFrame` does seem like a better identifier. I have yet to add any documentation, but plan to in the near future. And you're right, I shouldn't limit the annotation to a single method. Any other suggestions?

Comment: All methods called on `Atomic*` classes are handled atomically, which means `set` "unconditionally (and atomically) sets the boolean". The msPerFrame is probably a preference thing. As for other suggestions: None from my side as of now ;)